# how to change system DNS via flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with firebase so for some reason I must change the DNS of the android system to be able to use firebase. my question is how to change the DNS of the system from flutter or is there any way that I use one specific DNS for just my app and don't change the system dns.

Comment: check `PathMetric` class

Comment: Hi bro do you have any update on this? Thanks